# How can I change margins in "elsarticle" document class?

Tags: margins, elsarticle

I am using "elsarticle" document class for my Elsevier paper and I want to change the margins in all side to 2.5cm. How can I do this?  I used the code below:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{...}

....

....

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\bibliography{pose}

\end{document}
```

I used the code below to control the margins, but the height of the text is not proper.

```
\oddsidemargin = 0cm
\topmargin = 0cm
\textheight = 25cm
\textwidth = 16cm
```

because A4 paper is 21*30cm and I reduced 5cm and wrote 15*25 without any excess margin. What is the solution?

regards.

Comment: Also there is a blank page at first numbered 1. then my paper begins!

How strange is this class!!

please I should finish this work by tomorrow morning. it means I have just 8 hours without sleeping.

regards.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a good idea to switch to another document class the day before a deadline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

% \usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}% by courtesy of Mico

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. But how about the first excess blank page that is appeared in the paper?  what can I do to it?  this is the first time I use "elsarticle". I also have problem with reference part of the problem!

Comment: I know it is not a good idea but I know that I can do this with your help. Now I have just 2 problems. 1) First blank page. 2) I don't see "6. Reference"!

Comment: @Mico I swear I was looking for that one, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Mohammad Please ask a new question and make sure that both problems actually show up in a compilable example. Without it, we can only guess.

Comment: You need to use the `\documentclass` without any of the options, otherwise you'll get a conflict.

Comment: More specifically, you must avoid the 1p/3p/5p `\documentclass` options that change the margins themselves.