# How can I change the width of page in latex

Tags: header-footer, margins, document-classes, elsarticle

I am wring the paper that is formatted by elsarticle. However, the margin between text and left. right page look big. Hence, the text length is very narrow. Could I change it in the file

```
   \documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this for an article submission to Elsevier? If so, then that is something you don't need to worry about. If not, why don't you just use `article`?

Comment: Yes. I am going to submit to Elsevier. My paper is so long. I need to reduce the page by increase the length of width

Comment: ...and they're okay with that? Won't they just change it back to whatever dimensions they need/use for the journal, thereby making your changes moot?

Comment: No. They are not limited. However, I think if the paper is so long, it require the long time to review

Comment: So, to clarify, you simply want the article to look shorter? I say look because this will only be a change in appearance.

Comment: Yes. I just want to make it look short. Because the content is not change. If   the journal did not require the formatting. Could I use that way? (I.e \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered already:

[How can I change margins in "elsarticle" document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56267/how-can-i-change-margins-in-elsarticle-document-class)

So, apparently you can just use the geometry package, and set a margin that works for you:

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

However, I am pretty sure that if you submit your article to a journal, in the end they will apply their own template anyway, so this will not actually affect the final layout of the article once it is published.